# Alertdialog automatically do action after timer

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create an alertdialog which gives the user a yes or no choice but also if neither button is pressed in a certain timeframe a deafult action occurs. I was wondering if this was possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this is possible, but I recommend you to display a timer not to let the user with a poker face when its dialog gets closed with no interaction.

Here the steps to follow:

- To create a dialog use the `DialogFragment` with [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) tutorial to create one.
- To start a timer and get some callback calls when the time is ticking, use the `CountDownTimer`, in the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) you have an example.
- Finally when all the time is finished make a call to `DialogFragment#dismiss()` to close the dialog with no user interaction.

Remember to cancel the timer if the user interacts with the dialog, so you avoid leaking some resources.